# AFNetworking 3.0 Multipart form data for uploading image error

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, image-uploading, afnetworking-3

I've been trying to upload an image to my AWS server using multipart form data afnetworking 3.0 but apparently, every image I tried to upload ended up in the failure block. The codes in written in objective-c.

```
- (NSURLSessionUploadTask *)uploadImageTask:(NSMutableDictionary *)dictionary
{
    NSString *s3BucketUrl = [dictionary objectForKey:@"s3BucketUrl"];

    NSData *imageData = [dictionary objectForKey:@"imageData"];

    NSString *contentType = [dictionary objectForKey:@"contentType"];

    NSString *filename = [dictionary objectForKey:@"filename"];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer] multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:s3BucketUrl parameters:dictionary constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {

       [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"file" fileName:filename mimeType:contentType];
    } error:nil];

    AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];

    NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask = [[NSURLSessionUploadTask alloc] init];
    uploadTask = [manager
                  uploadTaskWithStreamedRequest:request
                  progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull uploadProgress) {
                      // This is not called back on the main queue.
                      // You are responsible for dispatching to the main queue for UI updates
                      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                          //Update the progress view

                      });
                  }
                  completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * _Nonnull response, id  _Nullable responseObject, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                      if (!error) {

                          if (self.delegate != nil && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(onUploadImageTask:)])
                          {
                              [self.delegate onUploadImageTask:nil];
                          }

                      } else {

                          if (self.delegate != nil && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(onUploadImageTask:)])
                          {
                              [self.delegate onUploadImageTask:error];
                          }
                      }
                  }];

    [uploadTask resume];

    return uploadTask;
}
```

**The error I'm getting is**

> Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1011 "Request failed: bad request (400)" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x170248940 {Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1016 "Request failed: unacceptable content-type: application/xml" UserInfo={com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.response= { URL: https://....s3.amazonaws.com/ } { status code: 400, headers {
>           Connection = close;
>           "Content-Type" = "application/xml";
>           Date = "Tue, 20 Dec 2016 01:53:47 GMT";
>           Server = AmazonS3;
>           "Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
>           "x-amz-id-2" = ".....";
>           "x-amz-request-id" = ....;
>       } },

I tried changing the content-type for the response serializer and still fail.

Comment: tried octet-stream as the content-type?

Comment: @Joshua how to proceed octet-stream as content type and what does it do?

Comment: A good explanation will be here: https://www.reference.com/technology/octet-stream-ecf0fe1dd4c152a0 and based on the error it seems that the server you are sending to does not accept application/xml

Comment: yeah thats why I have been trying to configure the content-type but everytime i tried to change it then request time out

Comment: @WongWengkeong I have created a custom method for uploading image and video both, If you want then I will post my answer

Comment: @Jecky yes Jecky, please do post your answer. I have stucked for hours here. It would be really helpful

Comment: @WongWengkeong Please check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use this method**

```
-(void)callWebserviceToUploadImageWithParams:(NSMutableDictionary *)_params imgParams:(NSMutableDictionary *)_imgParams videoParms:(NSMutableDictionary *)_videoParams action:(NSString *)_action success:(void (^)(id))_success failure:(void (^)(NSError *))_failure

{
    if ([[AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager] isReachable]) {
        //Here BASE_URL is my URL of web service
        NSString *urlString = [BASE_URL stringByAppendingString:_action];
        NSLog(@"URL : %@",urlString);
        NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
        [urlRequest setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
        [urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
        NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
        [urlRequest addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];
       // [urlRequest setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-type: application/json"]
        NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
        [_params enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock: ^(NSString *key, NSString *object, BOOL *stop) {
            [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n",key] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",object] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        }];
        [_imgParams enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock: ^(NSString *key, NSData *object, BOOL *stop) {
            if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSData class]]) {
                if (object.length > 0) {
                    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
                    NSLog(@"Timestamp:%@",TimeStamp);
                    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"; filename=\"%@.jpg\"\r\n",key,TimeStamp] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
                    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
                    [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:object]];
                }

            }
        }];
        [_videoParams enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock: ^(NSString *key, NSData *object, BOOL *stop) {
            if (object.length > 0) {
                [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
                NSLog(@"Timestamp:%@",TimeStamp);
                [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"; filename=\"%@.mp4\"\r\n",key,TimeStamp] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
                [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
                [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:object]];
            }
        }];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [urlRequest setHTTPBody:body];
        AFHTTPSessionManager* manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
        manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = nil;


        NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [manager dataTaskWithRequest:urlRequest completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, id responseObject, NSError *error) {
            if (error) {
                NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
                if( _failure )
                {
                    _failure( error) ;
                }
            } else {
                if( _success )
                {
                    _success( responseObject ) ;
                }
            }
        }];
        [dataTask resume];
    }
    else
    {
        [Utility showInterNetConnectionMessage];
        NSError *error;
        if( _failure )
        {
            _failure( error) ;
        }
    }
}
```

**If you are not uploading any video or image then give as nil**

**USE:**

```
#pragma -mark callwebservice for login
  -(void)callWebserviceFor_upload_Sticker {
    // Check whether Company user login or Individual User login.
    [SVProgressHUD setDefaultMaskType:SVProgressHUDMaskTypeClear];

    //user_id, user_token, emoji_weburl(optional), emoji_picture(file)
    NSMutableDictionary *dict_user_data = [Utility getUserPlistData];
    NSMutableDictionary *params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [params setValue:[dict_user_data valueForKey:@"user_id"] forKey:@"user_id"];
    [params setValue:[dict_user_data valueForKey:@"user_token"] forKey:@"user_token"];
    NSLog(@"%@",params);

    NSMutableDictionary *imgParams = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [imgParams setValue:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img_to_upload, 0) forKey:@"emoji_picture"];

    void ( ^successed )( id _responseObject ) = ^( id _responseObject )
    {
        NSLog(@"%@",_responseObject);
        //Your logic after success
    } ;
    void ( ^failure )( NSError* _error ) = ^( NSError* _error ) {
        [SVProgressHUD showErrorWithStatus:@"Failed"];
    } ;

[[WebServiceHendler sharedManager]callWebserviceToUploadImageWithParams:params imgParams:imgParams videoParms:nil action:UPDATE_EMOJI success:successed failure:failure];
}
```